# Why I can't evaluate a function inside CssClass?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, eval, linkbutton

I am inside a Repeater, and I'm trying to call the `IsExperienced` function from CssClass (as I usually do):

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="CheckBox" 
    CssClass='wall-item-checkbox <%# IsExperienced() %>' 
    runat="server" 
    onclick="CallFunction">
    &nbsp;
</asp:LinkButton>
```

but this time it prints `class=wall-item-checkbox <%# IsExperienced() %>` on the HTML.

Comment: Out of interest, does this work if you remove `wall-item-checkbox`? You can also use just the client-side `class` attribute instead of `CssClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an odd approach in the first place given that you can access that control within the repeater `ItemDataBound` event, better to separate code from markup.

Why don't you do this instead:

```
protected void fooRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        LinkButton lnkButton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox");
        lnkButton.CssClass += string.Format(" {0}", IsExperienced());
    }
}
```